# dose 2ghz brand drvice support 5ghz wifi signals

Tags: wireless-networking

am thinking to buy a new tp-link wifi card which supports dual band. if i use that wificard as a hotspot. Will my phone can see 5Ghz frequency of this usb adapter and does it will this increase my signal radios as compared to 2Ghz brands ?

card is tp-link-tl-wdn3200-n600-wireless-dual-band-usb-adapte

Comment: This entirely depends on the adapter.  If it only broadcasts at 5GHz and your phone can only connect to 2.4GHz networks then your phone will be unable to connect to the adapter.

Answer (score -2):

Using a dual band wifi card as a router for others to connect to (hotspot) will indeed allow all other devices to see the 5ghz signal (once it has been enabled and configured with an SSID, password, etc.).

Yes, the 5ghz side is faster - primarily due to the fact that the band is so uncrowded and thus a lot less interference is present. It also has greater bandwidth capabilities.

For example, I have 110mbs download. On 2ghz my laptop will pull about 80mbs and on the 5ghz side it will draw down around 112mbs.

Roger

Comment: i have asus zenfone 4 and if i create hotshot in desktop using that wifi adapter with 5Ghz signals then can my phone will able to find it ? because i didn't try this things before